# set up if statement for temperature conversions?

Tags: python, if-statement, temperature

The given function is:

```
def Temp_Conv(Temp_in, case):
```

Where Temp_in is an integer, and case is a string. Case can be inputted as 'C2F' (celsius to fahrenheit) or 'F2C' (fahrenheit to celsius). I only need to convert celsius to fahrenheit, so when case=='C2F', then I will apply the conversion formula. However, if case=='F2C' then the return must be 'Wrong case value'.
This is how I set up my program:

```
def Temp_Conv(Temp_in,case):
    if case=='C2F':
        return ((Temp_in*(9/5)) + 32)
    if case=='F2C'
        return 'Wrong case value'
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Looks like what you described is what you implemented. Is there an issue when you run it?

Comment: Run the program and you will get to know whether it's right or wrong

Comment: Unfortunately i'm unable to run the program because I was given no input values, just that following information for an assignment. Is there a way I can make my own input values?

Comment: `Temp_Conv` is a function, call the function passing the relevant info to the function.
`result = Temp_Conv(20, "C2F")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if your funciton works.

```
def Temp_Conv(Temp_in,case):
    if case=='C2F':
        return ((Temp_in*(9/5)) + 32)
    if case=='F2C':
        return 'Wrong case value'

case = input("please enter a case: ")
temp = 30
print(Temp_Conv(temp, case))
```

This should run the function to see if it works or not.

Comment: Whenever I try to run this, the output is 'C2F' and the program keeps looping infinitely. Strange, do you know why?

Comment: Nevermind, I tried typing case=input('C2F') because I thought that's what you meant, but I entered "please enter a case" and then afterwards I typed 'C2F' and the output was 86, so it worked! Thank you so much.